# Is there a reason to prefer Symbol.keyFor() over Symbol.prototype.description?

Tags: javascript, string, function, class, object

In JavaScript, I can create Symbol -primitives like this:

```
const ex1 = Symbol('example1');
const ex2 = Symbol.for('example2');
```

And I can get the original string that was used to create the Symbol by accessing the `Symbol.prototype.description`, ***or*** by calling the `Symbol.keyFor()` -method like so:

```
ex1.description; // 'example1'
ex2.description; // 'example2'
// OR
Symbol.keyFor(ex1); // undefined
Symbol.keyFor(ex2); // 'example2'
```

My questions are;

- Is there any difference between the two methods, other than `Symbol.keyFor` not working for Symbols that are not in the global registry (i.e. created from `Symbol.for()`)? It seems to me they are otherwise used to achieve the exact same thing.
- Is there a reason to ever prefer using `Symbol.keyFor()` instead of `Symbol.prototype.description`? Since the `description` works for all Symbols, while `keyFor` works only for ones in the global registry.

Comment: Well, it lets you find out whether any given symbol is part of the global registry or not, which might be pretty useful